# How to style favicon in title of html

Tags: html, google-chrome, title, favicon

I have been creating a replica of the Google Homepage, and I added the Google logo using a Favicon. Unfortunately, it isn't sized the way I'd like, and it is also square shaped. I was going to style it, but then I realized I wasn't sure how since it isn't just an image tag. Is there any to to style it? Here is my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GoogleHome.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Google</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the image:
  [Google Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru3o8.png)

Comment: You'd have to edit the image in an image editor to make style changes to it.

Comment: You can't do it thru your code. I mean is not good and efficient at all. You have to give it the size from the image editor.

Comment: Any of you guys know how to create a circular image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unfortunately  no way to style the icon of an HTML webpage.
You would have to do this in a form of image editor.

Good luck!

Sincerly Herman

Comment: I appreciate it and I understand. What I was trying to do is make the image itself circular. I can make the logo circular in photoshop but how do I make the background and canvas itself circular?

Comment: In theory, if you are able to create a logo which is round and with a transparent background, you should get what you want. Make sure the background is transparent and that you have exported the image from photoshop correctly. Some export settings from photoshop may take the transparacy away..

Comment: Thanks. I believe it was transparent, but I will make sure.